# mysql table data, in ubuntu, cuts off of rows in terminal. How can view the whole list?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I'm using

```
SELECT DISTINCT something FROM something;
```

to display 1660 rows, the problem is my ubuntu terminal is only showing a couple hundred or so and I can no longer scroll up to view the whole list.

How can view the whole list?

Comment: Do you really need the whole list?

Comment: @juergend well it's a list of post names and I'm looking for a particular post that I don't really know the name of but I'll know it when I see it, if that makes sense :)

Comment: @juergend I think `>mysql pager less;` is what I was looking for

Comment: Then you can write an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To view a scrollable list of lots of rows, that your terminal might cut off, I used this mysql terminal command:

`>mysql pager less;`

It lets you use the arrow keys to scroll your terminal, to view an entire set of results.

To escape back to the default view use

`>mysql nopager;`

Answer (score 1):

The default Ubuntu terminal is GnomeTerminal. If you select on the menu item Edit>Preferences>Scrolling, you can set the number of Scrollback lines remembered.

If you use `emacs`, you can run mysql from within emacs using `M-x sql-mysql`. Then the output would be part of an emacs buffer.

Comment: I'll give you a tick because it kind of answered my question and I didn't know to do that anyway, but in regards to sql I this accomplished what I wanted `>mysql pager less;`

Comment: @UzumakiDev: You don't have to accept my answer; you can post your own answer (and accept it).

Comment: okay, I'll post the answer, I just like handing out points :p